# Washing machine overflow tube spills water - cheap solution

Tags: plumbing

When my washing machine empties into the drain pipe it overflows initially, I tried running a snake thru the drain pipe - no luck.  Finally leaned a piece of plexglass against the wall into a mud tray to catch the water.  Not the best solution.  I saw in a boating magazine a gizmo (cleanwayfuelfill.com) that catches fuel overflow when fueling up.  It looked like something that might work in my situation.  I got the gizmo with the included adapters, it worked, no more water spills, no leaks.[image]

Comment: Yes this is a unique way to solve your problem; basically just creating a larger standpipe to hold the volume until it has time to drain, nice. No, this question does not align with the way this site is supposed to work, so I am voting to close. next time post the problem as a question, then post your solution as an answer and accept it as the best answer if you think it is.

Comment: This is why many installations have a "laundry tub" next to the washing machine. Even if you never use it to wash anything by hand (I find it very useful for cleaning tools after painting or any messy activity), it works great as a way to hold the water until the sewer pipe is able to take it all. But as @JimmyFix-it noted, this is not the usual format for Q&A here.

Comment: This works, but I would recommend getting a professional drain cleaning done.  A snake may maintain an opening in the drain line  but not clean to the full diameter.   The problem may get worse with time.